# Get List entries of a specific subtype using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections, ienumerable

I have three classes: Foo, Bar, and Baz.  Bar and Baz both extend Foo, which is abstract.  I have a List of type Foo, filled with Bars and Bazes.  I want to use a LINQ Where clause to return all of one type.  Something like:

```
class Bar : Foo
{
  public Bar()
  {
  }
}

class Baz : Foo
{
  public Baz()
  {
  }
}

List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>() { bar1, bar2, foo1, foo2, bar3 };
List<Bar> bars;
bars = (List<Bar>)foos.Where(o => o.GetType() == Type.GetType("Bar"));
```

When I do this I get an error: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[Foo]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Bar]'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx): filter out `Bar` items and materialize them into list:

```
List<Bar> bars = foos
  .OfType<Bar>()
  .ToList();
```

**Edit:** If you want `Bar` instances only, but not `Baz` even if/when `Baz` is derived from `Bar` you have to add a condition:

```
List<Bar> bars = foos
  .OfType<Bar>()
  .Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof(Bar)) // Bar only
  .ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't give me an error, but it returns entries of both Bar and Baz.  Weird.

Comment: @GameKyuubi: Does `Baz` extends `Bar`? If so, `Baz` is `Bar`

Comment: No, both Baz and Bar extend Foo only.

Comment: @GameKyuubi: if it doesn't give an error, then `List<Bar> bars` can contain `Baz` items iff (if and only if) `Baz` is `Bar`: either `Baz` has been derived from `Bar`, or `Bar` is an interface implemented by `Baz`. `List<Bar>` declaration leaves no chances for other possibilities.

Comment: Alright, that did it.  The where clause prunes out the Bazes.  But why?  Why does .OfType<Bar>() return things of type other than Bar?

Comment: @GameKyuubi: `OfType<T>()` filter out all the items that of type `T`, not *exactly* of type T. So if you put, say `OfType<Object>()` you'll get the entire iterator (all objects are of type `Object`)

Comment: But in my case Baz is not derived from Bar.  Baz and Bar derive directly from Foo.  I'll post up my extension classes.

Comment: Nevermind.  I must have mistyped the type in oftype.  It works without the Where clause now.